# Recovering a RAID array

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I accidentally corrupted my build of Ubuntu 17.10 through a forced reboot (on a 5th hard drive). In my system I had 4 other hard drives part of a RAID5 array. Now that I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 again, how do I recover my array and data?

I've tried both

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --uuid=XXXXXXXXXX
```

and

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
```

and I can then get it to mount, but when I go to access the files, it prompts for a password and the folder is empty. All array members show active and clean.

NOTE: I made my /home directory on this RAID before the crash my moving and mounting it there.
Please see output below:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 

Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sde[4] sdb[0] sdd[2] sdc[1] 8790405120 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU] 
bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk 
unused devices: <none>
```

Output below for

```
sudo parted --list /dev/md0

Model: ATA TS128GSSD370S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   128GB  127GB  ext4


Error: end of file while reading /dev/sdb
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? retry
Error: end of file while reading /dev/sdb
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? ignore                                               
Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will
be used.
OK/Cancel? ok                                                             
Model: ATA ST3000VN000-1HJ1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA ST3000VN000-1HJ1 (scsi)                                        
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Error: /dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA ST3000VN000-1HJ1 (scsi)                                        
Disk /dev/sdd: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Error: end of file while reading /dev/sde
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? ignore
Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will
be used.
OK/Cancel? ok                                                             
Model: ATA ST3000VN000-1HJ1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Model: WD Elements 25A1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name      Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB  ntfs         Elements  msftdata


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 9001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  9001GB  9001GB  ext4
```

After 
    mount /dev/md0 /mnt

Output of
    ls -la /dev/md*
is

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 9, 0 Apr 13 16:31 /dev/md0

/dev/md:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   60 Apr 13 16:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4520 Apr 13 16:31 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Apr 13 16:31 0 -> ../md0
```

Comment: Post the error messages from the commands. Also post the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

Comment: No error messages from the commands. cat command yields the following:

Comment: cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sde[4] sdb[0] sdd[2] sdc[1]
      8790405120 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

Comment: Well, as you can see in the `md0` line, the raid5 is assembled perfectly as indicated by the `[UUUU]`.  Check with `sudo parted --list /dev/md0` if the partition table is alright?

Comment: @SimonSudler Output added to question. Thanks for your help so far. Looks like we're getting near it? (individual drives show unknown partition table?)

Comment: Your partition layout looks strange. On a RAID 5 there shouln'd be a boot partition. Have you tried mounting (`mount /dev/md1 /mnt`) the ext partition?

Comment: @SimonSudler did you mean md0? md1 does not exist. What I had originally done is create the RAID and migrate my home to point to the RAID

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the last entry. The ext4 on /dev/md0 locks okay, what happens if you `mount /dev/md1 /mnt`?

Comment: it returns that md1 doesn't exist

Comment: typo... `mount /dev/md0 /mnt` and post the output of `ls -la /dev/md*`

Comment: @SimonSudler Updated.

Comment: And the `mount /dev/md0 /mnt` worked? Can you see your files `ls -la /mnt`? I dont't since this is a RAID problem.

Comment: I see my old username (where presumably my old /home is), but I'm getting a permission denied when I attempt to access it through the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a raid Problem, more a permission issue. If you check the output of the `cat /proc/mdstat` command, you can see that the raid5 is assembled perfectly as indicated by the `[UUUU]` in the `md0` line.

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sde[4] sdb[0] sdd[2] sdc[1] 8790405120 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
unused devices: <none>
```

Also the partition table (loop for a loop-device) and the filesystem (ext4) are fine. After mounting the loop device with `mount /dev/md0 /mnt` you should see something like:

```
$ mount /dev/md0 /mnt
$ ls -la /mnt
  total 12
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 29  2016 .
  drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Dec  7 10:42 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  3 1001 2001 4096 Feb  6  2017 oldusername
```

Now you need to change the owner of the old user home to your current user:

```
$ sudo chown $(stat -c '%u:%g' ~/) /mnt/oldusername
$ ls -la /mnt
  total 12
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root        root         4096 Jun 29  2016 .
  drwxr-xr-x 10 root        root         4096 Dec  7 10:42 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  3 currentuser currentgroup 4096 Feb  6  2017 oldusername
```